# Direct proof that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is not a flat $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification, modules, exact-sequence

I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is not a flat $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$-module. The reasoning I have is the following.

We have an exact sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \to\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \to 0$ where the first map is multiplication by $p$ and the last map is the cokernel of the first map. This sequence does not split and hence $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is not a projective $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$-module. However every finitely presented flat module is projective. Clearly $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is finitely presented and not projective. Hence it is not flat.

> 1.) Is my reasoning correct ?
>   2.) Can we write down an exact sequence of $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$-modules which does not remain exact after tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Thanks !

Comment: Well, your sequence works.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I think it does not. Tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ leaves it unchanged.

Comment: No. It becomes $0 \to \mathbb{Z}/p \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z}/p \xrightarrow{=} \mathbb{Z}/p \to 0$.

Comment: @user90041 : Unimportant comment: *However every finitely presented flat module is projective...* Since $\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z$ is local, you could just comment that *all flat modules are projective.*

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I was making a mistake. I understand it now, thanks.